# How clear the same object from localStorage and increase quantity?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a client side shopping cart. Added products are saved in local storage, but how can increase product quantity if it is already added to local storage? I have function that adds product to local store and in this function I increase quantity, but products become duplicated.

```
Product.prototype.addObjToLocalStore = function() {
    var obj = {
        'name': this.name,
        'qty': this.qty,
        'price': this.price,
        'total': this.getPrice()
    }
    var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];

    for (k in oldItems) {
        if(oldItems[k].name == obj.name) {
            oldItems[k].qty += parseInt(obj.qty);
            localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems[k].qty));
        }
    }

    oldItems.push(obj);
    localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, regardless of whether or not you've found the item, you `oldItems.push(obj)` to it, duplicating the item.

So what I would do in this case is not use an array, but an object. The key of the object being the item's identifier (in your case, the name), and the value being the item's properties (quantity, price, etc). Like so:

```
Product.prototype.addObjToLocalStore = function() {
    // oldItems is an object, not an array
    var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsObject')) || {};
    // If it exists, grab its quantity. If not, 0.
    var oldQuantity = (oldItems[this.name] && oldItems[this.name].qty) || 0;
    var obj = {
        'name': this.name,
        'qty': oldQuantity + this.qty,
        'price': this.price,
        'total': this.getPrice()
    }

    // Replace the old entry with the new.
    // If doesn't exist, will be created.
    oldItems[this.name] = obj;

    // We're done here. Store the new object.
    logalStorage.setItem('itemsObject', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
};
```

Comment: Now object if he set in local storage always overwriting

Answer (score -1):

If you want to not duplicate your object delete two last lines:

```
 oldItems.push(obj);
 localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
```